# How to solve this error while installing pyaudio?

Tags: python

```
Complete output from command E:\python\project\audi\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DEEPAK~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vog_q_bd\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=ge
tattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DEEPAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-el4ifpw9\install-record
.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers E:\python\project\audi\venv\include\site\python3.7\PyAudio:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "E:\python\project\audi\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DEEPAK~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vog_q_bd\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DEEPAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-el4ifpw9\install-record.txt --single-version-ex
ternally-managed --compile --install-headers E:\python\project\audi\venv\include\site\python3.7\PyAudio" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DEEPAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vog_q_bd\PyAudio\
```

This is the error I got while trying to install the Pyaudio

Comment: Please use syntax highlighting to make your question more readable.
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: You solution is listed in the error `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools`